# Можно ли отправить FormData не через ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Можно ли отправить FormData не через ajax?

**UPD 1**
Интересует именно возможность отправить форму с перезагрузкой страницы.
И в FormData есть файлы, поэтому и используется FormData

**UPD 2**
Код для пояснения
https://jsfiddle.net/temoffey/q0g8tusf/1/

```js
var send_form = document.getElementById('send_form');
var file_input = document.getElementById('file_input');
var file_view = document.getElementById('file_view');
var file_list = [];

file_input.addEventListener('change', function() {

 for (i=0;i<this.files.length;i++) {
   file_list.push(this.files[i]);
  }
  
  file_view.innerText = '';
  for (i in file_list) {
   file_view.innerHTML = file_view.innerHTML + file_list[i].name + '<br />';
  }

});

send_form.addEventListener('submit', function() {

 var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('documents[]', file_list);
  
  // Что нужно, что бы form_data был отправлен?

});
```

```html
<form id="send_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" id="file_input" multiple />
  <br />
  <br />
  <div id="file_view"></div>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: А чем вам нативная отправка формы не угодила? Она ведь тоже по идее формДату отправляет и с перезагрузкой, просто укажите `action` в форме

Comment: При нативной отправке нельзя выбрать файлы из нескольких папок. При выборе второй раз, файлы выбранные в первый открепляются.

Comment: Ну вы можете как вариант просто после отправки через ajax перезагрузить страницу

Comment: Отправлять обязательно нужно клиенту? Если бы задачей было отправить просто запрос, я бы это сделал с помощью fetch в панели инструментов Chrome через консоль.

Answer (score 1):

Вот прекрасный пример [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects):

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456);
formData.append("userfile", fileInputElement.files[0]);
var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>';
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});
formData.append("webmasterfile", blob);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://foo.com/submitform.php");
request.send(formData);
```

Comment: Но нужно что бы отправка была не через Ajax